# Ansible: Create instances in different subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamic, tags, ansible, inventory

I'm trying to use Ansible to create two instances, one each in two subnets using the play below. I'm using exact_count with tag Name to keep track of instances. There are two issues here:

1. Ansible ends up creating two instances in the first subnet and reports [ok] for the second subnet.
2. Ansible doesn't seem to care about stopped instances. It creates new instances, instead of starting existing ones, or atleast considering them as part of the group of instances.

> ```
>   - name: Create kafka instances
>     with_items:
>       - "{{ vpc_pvt_subnet_2 }}"
>       - "{{ vpc_pvt_subnet_1 }}"
>     ec2:    
>       group: "{{ kafka_sg }}"  
>       key_name: "{{ ec2_keypair }}"  
>       region: "{{ region }}"  
>       image: "{{ ami_id }}"  
>       wait: true   
>       instance_type: "{{ kafka_inst_type }}"  
>       vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item }}"  
>       instance_tags:  
>         Name: "kafka-instance"          
>         Owner: data  
>       exact_count: 2   
>       count_tag:  
>         Name: "kafka-instance"  
>     register: ec2
> ```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the playbook here?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to create 1 EC2 instance in each subnet, one visible error in the snippet you provided is that the value of `exact_count` should be set to 1 (not 2) because `with_items` will loop to run `ec2` module twice in your playbook. You want each iteration to create exactly 1 instance.

Next, I will answer according to your questions -

1] You need to specify `zone` parameter as well to `ec2` module. Since `zone` is dynamic according to a `vpc_subnet_id`, I would suggest the following structure -

In your vars -

```
subnets:
  - { zone: "us-east-1a", vpc_pvt_subnet: "subnet-abcdafa5"}
  - { zone: "us-east-1b", vpc_pvt_subnet: "subnet-zyxwvb51"}
```

In the `ec2` task -

```
- name: "Create kafka instances"
  with_items: "{{ subnets }}"
  ec2:
    group: "{{ kafka_sg }}"
    key_name: "{{ ec2_keypair }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    image: "{{ ami_id }}"
    wait: true
    instance_type: "{{ kafka_inst_type }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.vpc_pvt_subnet }}"
    zone: "{{ item.zone }}"
    instance_tags:
      Name: "kafka-instance"
      Owner: "data"
    exact_count: 1
    count_tag:
      Name: "kafka-instance"
  register: ec2
```

2] Yes, the above way will always create new instance even if an instance already exists in a subnet with "stopped" state as if this instance never existed. If you want to explicitly start the "stopped" instances by tags, you can achieve that by passing the `state` parameter to a new `ec2` task - you cannot use `state` and `exact_count` parameters together in the same task.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer to the first question solved my problem, although I'm not sure why it isn't enough to specify only the subnet. In other words, why does Ansible require me to mention the zone again as the subnet is forever tied to a particular AZ anyway?  

I had tried using a separate ec2 task to start stopped instances, but I was running into a different issue that I cannot immediately remember. I think it was to do with waiting to let the instances start before running configuration tasks on them. I'll add a reply after I try this again (and mark this as answer then).

Thanks!

Comment: @urover did you ever get a chance to test this?