# Create a EC2 instance with 2 Subnet using playbooks

Tags: ansible

While trying to create single instance with 2 subnets with below playbook:

```
# Basic provisioning example
- name: Create AWS resources
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    subnets:
      - { zone: "us-west-2c", vpc_pvt_subnet: "subnet-ff9f89325"}
      - { zone: "us-west-2c", vpc_pvt_subnet: "subnet-7f9df6832"}

  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: create an EC2 instance
    with_items: "{{ subnets }}"
    ec2:
      key_name: testkey
      region:  us-west-2
      instance_type: r3.xlarge
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.vpc_pvt_subnet }}"
      zone: "{{ item.zone }}"
      image: ami-efd0428f
      wait: yes
      instance_tags:
          Name: "testinstance"
      exact_count: 1
      count_tag:
          Name: "testistance"
    register: ec2
```

For first subnet it says "changed" in response but for 2nd subnet it just sent a respone "OK"

**1st Subnet: changed: [localhost] => (item={u'vpc_pvt_subnet': u'subnet-ff9f89325', u'zone': u'us-west-2c'}) => {**

2nd subnet:

**ok: [localhost] => (item={u'vpc_pvt_subnet': u'subnet-7f9df6832', u'zone': u'us-west-2a'}) => {**

Can somebody help on this please?

Comment: Followed below link to create EC2 with 2 subnets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502494/ansible-create-instances-in-different-subnets/43974265#43974265

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of EC2 module

> count_tag: Used with 'exact_count' to determine how many nodes based
>   on a specific tag criteria should be running. This can be expressed in
>   multiple ways and is shown in the EXAMPLES section. For instance, one
>   can request 25 servers that are tagged with "class=webserver". The
>   specified tag must already exist or be passed in as the
>   'instance_tags' option.
>
> exact count: An integer value which indicates how many instances that
>   match the 'count_tag' parameter should be running. Instances are
>   either created or terminated based on this value.

Since you have count_tag: testinstance and exact_count set to 1, Ansible does not launch the secondary instance. changing the count to 2 should fix the issue in this case.

Comment: Hi @deepak, I am trying to create only one instance and wanted to associate it with two subnets. the reason i iterated for subnet keeping the exact_count value 1. keeping exact_count to 2 won't serve my need.

Comment: You cannot create an EC2 and associate it to two subnets, unless you have another ENI attached to the instance.

Comment: It's pretty much doable through hitting REST API directly to AWS. We had achieved this use case. I am exploring a way to do it through Ansible for administrative usages though

Comment: Hi Folks, Can someone please point me to the execution flaw in this script? the reason i am not able to create EC2 instance with 2 NICs

Comment: @Harsh,To achieve what you need, you would have to change the strategy. The way to approach this problem is, 1) Create the instance with only one subnet 2) Create an ENI with ec2_eni module in the required subnet and attach it to the instance.