# Use ansible to create ec2 instances in different AZ

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have created a playbook to deploy ec2 instances in different AZ. It fails when i add "with_items" for count zone and subnet. How to overcome this.

I have followed this [Ansible: Create instances in different subnets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502494/ansible-create-instances-in-different-subnets) but it did not work so created a new oone as i could not update it

playbook is here

```
- name: Deploy EC2 Master node
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars_files:
    - ~/aws-common/automation/ansible/config/var_input.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Get AWS credentials
      sts_assume_role:
        role_arn: "{{ role_arn }}"
        role_session_name: "{{ role_session_name }}"
      register: assumed_role
    - name: Provision a set of instances
      ec2:
         key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
         group: "{{ group }}"
         instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
         region: "{{ region }}"
         image: "{{ image }}"
         wait: "{{ wait }}"
         wait_timeout: "{{ wait_timeout }}"
         #count: "{{ count }}"
         count: "{{ item.ec2_count }}"
         instance_profile_name: "{{ instance_profile_name }}"
         instance_tags:
           Name: "{{ Name }}"
           deployer: "{{ deployer }}"
           resourceowner: "{{ resourceowner }}"
         monitoring: "{{ monitoring }}"
         ec2_zone: "{{ item.zone }}"
         vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.subnet }}"
         assign_public_ip: "{{ assign_public_ip }}"
         aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
         aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
         security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
         volumes:
         - device_name: /dev/sda1
           volume_type: gp2
           encrypted: true
           volume_name: HadoopMaster-rootvolume /
           volume_size: 100
           delete_on_termination: true
         - device_name: /dev/sdf
           volume_type: gp2
           encrypted: true
           volume_name:  HadoopMaster /edw/xxx
           volume_size: 70
           delete_on_termination: true
      with_items: "{{ ec2_zone_subnet }}"
      register: ec2

    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
      loop: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      delegate_to: "{{ item.public_dns_name }}"
      wait_for_connection:
        delay: 60
        timeout: 320
      loop: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- hosts: launched
  name: Mounting the attached EBS volumes
  user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
      - name: Run a script with arguments (free form)
        script: ~/files/format.sh
```

This is my entry in variable file

```
ec2_zone_subnet: [{"zone":"us-east-1a", "subnet":"subnet-5f87a23b", "ec2_count":1},{"zone":"us-east-1b", "subnet":"subnet-a9d2bd86","ec2_count":1},{"zone":"us-east-1c", "subnet":"subnet-0cab05cf89718e652","ec2_count":0},{"zone":"us-east-1d", "subnet":"subnet-079c66d30dcd53ce7","ec2_count":0}]
```

Error i get

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'subnet': u'subnet-0cab05cf89718e652', u'ec2_count': 0, u'zone': u'us-east-1c'}) => {"changed": false, "instance_ids": [], "instances": [], "item": {"ec2_count": 0, "subnet": "subnet-0cab05cf89718e652", "zone": "us-east-1c"}, "tagged_instances": []}
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'subnet': u'subnet-079c66d30dcd53ce7', u'ec2_count': 0, u'zone': u'us-east-1d'}) => {"changed": false, "instance_ids": [], "instances": [], "item": {"ec2_count": 0, "subnet": "subnet-079c66d30dcd53ce7", "zone": "us-east-1d"}, "tagged_instances": []}

TASK [Add new instance to host group] **********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/desind/aws-common/automation/ansible/files/testnew.yaml:51
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'instances'"}
```

The items now only have `ec2-count` `subnet`and `host`. I dont see the other attributes. Can someone help me with using register:ec2 and with_items

Comment: I dont know why someone has given a negative vote, the question is clear and valid .

Answer (score 0):

These are the following changes i made to playbook

1. Changed vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item }}"
2. with_items: "{{ subnet_ids }}"
3. 

```
- name: Add all instance private IPs to host group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.instances[0].private_ip }} instance_id={{ item.instance_ids[0] }} groups=launched
      with_items: '{{ ec2.results }}'

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      delegate_to: "{{ item.instances[0].private_ip }}"
      wait_for_connection:
        delay: 100
        timeout: 320
      loop: "{{ ec2.results }}"
```

4. Added subnets like this in variable file
   subnet_ids: [subnet-xxxx, subnet-axxx, subnet-xxxx]